# Difference-in-difference model: using difference year ranges for variables

Tags: regression, stata, difference-in-difference

I am working on a project that involves using the difference-in-difference method and was wondering if will ruin the outcome if I use a different year range for my independent and dependent variables.

Specifically, my research question is if airbnb usage has increased rental prices. My data for rental prices spans 2003-2016. The treatment would begin 2009 when airbnb started taking off. I would like to include zip-code specific demographic data from the census bureau; however, this is only available from 2010 onwards.

Is it possible to run the test with the 2003-2016 rental data and the 2010-2016 demographic data or must these ranges correspond?

Comment: You might not be able to do this exercise if you don't have controls for the better part of your sample. How are you supposed to estimate a DiD model when all controls are missing pre 2010?